# How to connect two computers across the web using VPN / LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, isp, p2p

I see this free LAN software offering P2P connectivity:
https://www.freelan.org/configuration_examples.html

it has this example:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

my question is - what defines "bob.someisp.com" and "alice.someotherisp.com" - how do they get a public address to their local computers on their home wifi networks??

If want to do this with two laptops - one at work and one at home - how can I can do this?

Comment: The Title says "*the web*", but I see nothing here about HTTP(S) protocol, which is what defines "the web".

Comment: Are you asking about having a public IP address, or about having a public domain name? (The linked page itself actually answers about the former.)